# Fitting an unknown curve.

Tags: exponential-function, bessel-functions, trigonometric-series

Have anyone seen this curve? Does it look like a known analytical function? I just know that it goes to zero in the infinite. I will be happy with any information.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like it goes to $0$ at infinity.  Could be a bimodal normal (or multimodal if there are several peaks that aren't shown).

Comment: It reminds me of something I saw in a physics course... Do you have any context for this graph?

Comment: Perhaps [damped harmonic oscillator](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Mplwp_resonance_zeta_envelope.svg/300px-Mplwp_resonance_zeta_envelope.svg.png)?

Comment: The diference between the E[(V^H V)^n] - E[V^H V]^n, where V is a Vandermonde matrix with a uniform randon variable as the argument. I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

An attempt with two logistic functions :

[image]